# WPF - WebView YouTube Video - Force Fullscreen

Tags: xml, wpf, html, webview, youtube

I am trying to play a YouTube video in my application, by using a webview. My current xml code is this: `<WebView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" Margin="89,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="681" Source="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&amp;html5=True "/>`

The video plays, but I need it to automatically go fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height of the webview and stretch the alignment properties. Try this.

```
<WebView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         Source="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTl3U6aSd2w&amp;html5=True " />
```